# module is not defined at node_modules/core-js/internals/global.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, rollupjs, core-js

I'm building a library in TypeScript, and I'm trying to test it. As It involves browser API I'm testing it using `@web/test-runner` and `chai`.

I'm using TypeScript, and some libraries are commonjs modules, so I'm using Rollup to bundle all of that into something the browser can use.

My rollup config is as follow:

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import sourceMaps from 'rollup-plugin-sourcemaps';
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

const pkg = require('./package.json');

const libraryName = 'AGreatLibrary';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    { file: pkg.main, name: libraryName, format: 'umd', sourcemap: true },
    { file: pkg.module, format: 'es', sourcemap: true },
  ],
  plugins: [
    json(),
    nodePolyfills(),
    typescript(),
    commonjs(),
    nodeResolve({ browser: true, preferBuiltins: false }),
    sourceMaps(),
    babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled', exclude: [/\bcore-js\b/, /\bwebpack\/buildin\b/] }),
  ],
};
```

My babel config

```json
{
  "presets":
  [
      [
          "@babel/env",
          {
              "targets":
              {
                  "edge": "17",
                  "firefox": "60",
                  "chrome": "67",
                  "safari": "11.1"
              },
              "useBuiltIns": "usage",
              "corejs": "3"
          }

      ]
  ],
  "minified": true
}
```

My test file

```js
import { Client } from "../lib/index.es.js";
import { expect } from '@esm-bundle/chai';

it('Should create a Client', () => {
  let client = new Client("123", true);
  expect(client.accessToken).to.equal("123");
});

it('Should auth', async () => {
  let client = new Client("123", true);
  let resp = await client.tryAuth();
  expect(resp.ok).to.be.true;
});
```

But when I run my test (`web-test-runner "test/**/*.test.ts" --node-resolve`)

I get the following error

```
 Browser logs:
      ReferenceError: module is not defined
        at node_modules/core-js/internals/global.js:6:0
```

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fix it!

```js
plugins: [
    commonjs(),
    json(),
    nodePolyfills(),
    typescript(),
    nodeResolve({ browser: true, preferBuiltins: false }),
    sourceMaps(),
    babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled', exclude: [/\bcore-js\b/, /\bwebpack\/buildin\b/] }),
  ],
```

`commonjs` should be on top of the array.

Comment: This worked for me! I was getting an error about "module is not defined"  in apps that consumed a library I had bundled with rollup. Changing the order so that commonjs() was first fixed the issue! Thank you very much!